# Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to use ESP8266 module and i used esp8266wifi.h.
but it doesn't work :( Will you help me?? Here's my codes. I tried to find multiple libraries of "ESP8266WiFi.h", but i couldn't find any of multiple libraries.

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include  "WiFiUDP.h"


const char* ssid = "your ssid";
const char* password = "your password";

WiFiUDP Udp;
unsigned int localUdpPort = 4210;
char incomingPacket[255];
char replyPacket[] = "Hi there! Got the message.";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);


  connectWifi();


  Udp.begin(localUdpPort);

}

void loop() {

  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if(packetSize){
    Serial.printf("Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n", packetSize,         Udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), Udp.remotePort());
    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      incomingPacket[len] = 0;
    }
    Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);

    // send back a reply, to the IP address and port we got the packet from
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(replyPacket);
    Udp.endPacket();
    delay(1000); // Need a delay otherwise the data is not sent Was 3000
  }

}


void connectWifi(){
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);

  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");

  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("");
}
```

And here's my error messages. And will you tell me what "queue.h" means?? I can't find it.

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:33:0,

 Used: C:\Program
             from C:\Users\user\Desktop\sketch_dec18b\sketch_dec18b\sketch_dec18b.ino:1:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFiType.h:26:10: fatal error: 
queue.h: No such file or directory

#include <queue.h>

      ^~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager and delete the library. it is bundled with the boards package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you would like to use ESP8266 as a standalone module (not as a secondary MCU, controlled by AT commands) but according to the log, the compiler is trying to translate for Arduino/Genuino Uno board.
I think the first step should be to check the board settings and install the necessary packages, if the required one is not available.

[Board settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAkPI.png)

Comment: The hint is the line in the compiler output that says what platform it's compiling for: Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno". To use ESP8266, you need to set the platform (tools/board menu) to a platform matching your hardware. Often the ESP8266 hardware manufacturer has documentation describing how to install support for their board. For example, the Sparkfun ESP8266 Thing Dev board Hookup Guide has a section on how to install support for that board: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-development-board-hookup-guide/setting-up-arduino